# Sublime Text 2 Terminal plugin

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I installed the plugin `Sublime Terminal` in Sublime Text 2. The shortcut to open the terminal in the correct folder is `CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+T`.

When I press the shortcut keys then `Windows Powershell` is opened.

Can I configure this plugin so it opens `PuTTy` and not `Windows Powershell`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Terminal` and select `Settings-User`, which should open a blank file. Copy the content below into the file, changing the path to the location of your `putty.exe` file.

```json
{
    "terminal": "c:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\putty.exe"
}
```

Save the file, and you should now be able to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open PuTTY.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question: Is there a possibility to run a shortcut of PuTTy and not the exe itself? Because then the shortcut can have extra parameters like loading a putty session, auto login with login and password